# How to have a button in Django template to add more form variable? Then how to process the multiple forms in views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 questions:

1. How to code a button to be able to add 1 or more duplicate form variable in template? I want to have a `product_create` page with a `Product` that may have multiple `Color` and `Thickness`.
2. Then how to save the `Product` with multiple `Color` and `Thickness` in `views.py` to database? Do I need `for` loop?

My 4 related models in `models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    video = models.URLField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class ColorParent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ProductColor(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(ColorParent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProductThickness(models.Model, MeasurementUnits):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dimension = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Thickness in International SI unit',
                                            null=True, blank=True)
    dimension_unit = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                      choices=MeasurementUnits.si_base_units,
                                      default=MeasurementUnits.millimetre, null=True, blank=True)
    alias = models.CharField(verbose_name='Thickness in Imperial unit',
                             max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    alias_unit = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                  choices=MeasurementUnits.imperial_base_units,
                                  default=MeasurementUnits.inch, null=True, blank=True)
```

My `forms.py`:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_id', 'video']

class ColorParentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ColorParent
        fields = ['name']

class ProductColorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductColor
        fields = ['color']

class ProductThicknessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductThickness
        fields = ['dimension', 'dimension_unit',
                  'alias', 'alias_unit']
```

My `views.py`:

```
def product_create_view(request):
    product_form = ProductForm(request.POST, prefix='product_form')
    color_form = ProductColorForm(request.POST, prefix='color_form')
    thickness_form = ProductThicknessForm(request.POST, prefix='thickness_form')

   if product_form.is_valid() and color_form.is_valid() and thickness_form.is_valid():
      product = product_form.save()  # save parent modelform first.
      color = color_form.save(commit=False)  # do not commit immediately for child modelform.
      thickness = thickness_form.save(commit=False)

      color.product = product  # pair the color with created product first.
      color.save()  # proceed to save.
      thickness.product = product
      thickness.save()
   context = {
        'product_form': product_form,
        'color_form': color_form,
        'thickness_form': thickness_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'product_visualizers/product_create.html', context)
```

My current `product_create.html` template:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

   <p>Product ID {{product_form.product_id }}</p>
   <p>Color Parent {{color_form.color}}</p>  # Button target to add more {{color_form.color}}
   <p>Video URL {{product_form.video}}</p>

   <h3>Technical Specifications</h3>
   <h4>Thickness Options</h4>
   <p>  # Button target to add more {{thickness_form.*}}
      Dimension: {{thickness_form.dimension}} {{thickness_form.dimension_unit}}
      Alias: {{thickness_form.alias}} {{thickness_form.alias_unit}}
   </p>

   <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
</form>
```